# Laravel: Multiple public path for one app?

Tags: php, laravel-5, ssl-certificate

I have 3 websites that are strongly connected together, this means they all use the same storage folder and the same database.

I created one Laravel app for all those three domains and I can distinguish between the websites by checking the `url` with middleware like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $server = str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    if($server == env('domain_a'))
    {
      setOrga(\Config::get('constants.domain_a'));
    }
    elseif($server == env('domain_b'))
    {
      //....
```

The problem is that I only have single-domain SSL certificates and I cannot set 3 different SSL certificates to the same path.

I was thinking of changing `/www/myProject/app/public/` to three paths like:

`/www/myProject/app/public/1` 
`/www/myProject/app/public/2` 
`/www/myProject/app/public/3`

and in each folder I place an `index.php` file with

```
<?php

   include('../index.php');
```

However, I am not sure if this is compatible with the way Laravel works. Could this cause any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by purchasing a multi-domain SSL certificate.